# S3 Subdomain for Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, subdomain

I would like to serve a static website from an Amazon S3 bucket, but for a subdomain to be redirected to a Django application. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just configure dns:

```
example.com CNAME s3.amazonaws.com (or s3-external-3.amazonaws.com for europe)
django.example..com  A 10.10.10.10 (ip's of server where you running django)
```

This is probably best way to do it.

Or make another bucket for django.example.com, set default page, and use website redirect location from Metadata in aws control panel.